# Failed to install initramfs-tools

Tags: apt, 20.04, dpkg, initramfs

Im running Ubuntu server 20.04LTS. I had an error of apt install, please tell me what I should do to solve this problem.

image: img-5.15.0-1023-azure

Command:
`sudo apt-get install -reinstall initramfs-tools`

Results:

```
Reading package lists... 0%
Reading package lists... 100%
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... 0%
Building dependency tree... 0%
Building dependency tree... 50%
Building dependency tree... 50%
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... 0%
Reading state information... 0%
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 9248 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
0% [Working]
            
Get:1 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 initramfs-tools all 0.136ubuntu6.7 [9248 B]
80% [1 initramfs-tools 9248 B/9248 B 100%]
                                          
100% [Working]
              
Fetched 9248 B in 0s (21.0 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 211910 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../initramfs-tools_0.136ubuntu6.7_all.deb ...
Unpacking initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.7) over (0.136ubuntu6.7) ...
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.7) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.7) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-1023-azure
cryptsetup: WARNING: osencrypt: key file 
    /mnt/azure_bek_disk/LinuxPassPhraseFileName has insecure ownership, see 
    /usr/share/doc/cryptsetup/README.Debian.gz.
cryptsetup: WARNING: Skipping root target osencrypt: uses a key file
+ PREREQS=udev
+ mount -a
+ cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/disk/by-partuuid/a6747a6e-d623-4e29-be45-02e96664ae40 osencrypt --header /boot/luks/osluksheader -d /mnt/azure_bek_disk/LinuxPassPhraseFileName
Device osencrypt already exists.
+ exit 0
Error 24 : Write error : cannot write compressed block 
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 lz4 -9 -l 24
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-1023-azure with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Is your /boot filesystem full? `df -h;df -i`

Comment: Thank you for your reaction.
It does not look full.

```
$ df -h
Filesystem                                               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2                                                248M  118M  118M  51% /boot

$ df -i
Filesystem                                                Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda2                                                  65536    599    64937    1% /boot
```